# I'm having issues looping through a tuple

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, tuples

I'm writing a program to simulate a bank scenario. It allows users (once they have logged in) to display their balance, withdraw and deposit money, and will eventually contain a transfer subroutine.

My problem is the login subroutine. I am having trouble getting my code to loop through both accounts in the tuple that saves them. I can log in to the first account and perform all the code's functions with that account but when I try to access the second account, I get the error message telling me that the account is not found. I am very certain that this is to do with the way I have written my loop but I cannot figure out how to fix it.

If someone could provide me with a solution that I can use to fix this error then I would be very grateful. If it is possible, could the solution also stick to the general format of my code and not be one where I have to create new functions and change the entire body of my LogOn function?

Here is the code:

```
accounts=[
["Luke",'00001','1234',1337],
["Louis",'00002','4321',420],
]

name = ""       
x = []          

def LogOn():
    global name        
    global x
    print ("Welcome to the Bank of Bailey")
    accnum = raw_input("-please enter your account number-")        
    if len(accnum) != 5:              
        print("That number is not valid, please enter a valid number")
        LogOn()
    else:
        for x in range(0,len(accounts)):          
            if accnum in accounts[x][1]:            
                name = accounts[x][0]              
                print ("Account found")
                pin = raw_input("-please enter your pin-")         
                if pin in accounts[x]:          
                    print ("Pin found")
                    MainMenu()           
                else:           
                    print("Pin not found")
                    print("Please try again")
                    LogOn()         
                    break
            else:             
                print("Account not found")
                print("Please try again")
                LogOn()
```

Comment: This doesn't completely answer your question, but it is generally a bad idea to make a function repeat by calling itself. It complicates the debugging process, and can cause crashes in long-running programs when Python reaches its maximum recursion depth. Consider using `while` when you want code to repeat an unknown number of times.

Comment: You titled this "looping through a tuple" and I haven't found a tuple yet...you're looking in an array, or a list of lists.....

Comment: @Kevin: I would not say "generally". I would say that it's maybe not the best solution in this case, but recursion is generally good for some algorithms (and programming languages).

Comment: @Markon: Sure, recursion has its place, and in some languages (like Haskell) it's the preferred (or only) way to do looping. But Python isn't Haskell. Python has a recursion limit, and it can't do tail call optimization, so it's best to avoid recursion in Python unless you're implementing an algorithm that is naturally suited to recursion, eg when working with recursive data structures, like trees.

Comment: @PM2Ring I know that Python is well known for its performance issues with recursion, though, as I said in the previous comment, the word "generally" is wrong here - considering that the OP, from my understanding, is learning Computer Science at school/uni. The problem with recursion is pretty specific to Python, and, furthermore, it's very specific to this case as recursion is not necessary, but for example you (as you might know) use recursion in Python every time you read subdirectories/files in a directory - so it's not "generally".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few observations:

- The else branch is called on the first iteration when x=0. You need to finish the for loop, then branch if the account has not been found.
- if pin in accounts[x] is a security hole because it allows people to use their name or account number as their pin!
- "if accnum in account[1]" should be "if accnum == account[1]"

Hope that helps!

```
    accounts=[
    ["Luke",'00001','1234',1337],
    ["Louis",'00002','4321',420],
    ]

    name = ""       
    x = []          

    def LogOn():
        global name        
        global x
        print ("Welcome to the Bank of Bailey")
        accnum = raw_input("-please enter your account number-")        
        if len(accnum) != 5:              
            print("That number is not valid, please enter a valid number")
            LogOn()
        else:
            found = False
            for account in accounts:
                if accnum == account[1]:
                    found = True
                    name = account[0]              
                    print ("Account found")
                    pin = raw_input("-please enter your pin-")         
                    if pin in account[2]:          
                        print ("Pin found")
                        MainMenu()
                    else:
                        print("Pin not found")
                        print("Please try again")
                        LogOn()  
                        break

            if not found:
                print("Account not found")
                print("Please try again")
                LogOn()
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is:

```
if accnum in accounts[x][1]:
     do something
else:             
     print("Account not found")
     print("Please try again")
     LogOn()
```

The else branch is called already for the first iteration (with x = 0)!
You should check after the while-loop if an account was found and otherwise print your error message.

Instead of recursing to `LogOn()` you could better use an outer (endless-)while-loop which calls `LogOn()`. In LogOn then just do a `return` in error case.

Answer (score 1):

I like @TimSC's answer, but I'll add a few more observations:

- `LogOn` is not a good function name; it should be `log_on` to match [PEP8 naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names) (`LogOn` suggests it is a class rather than a function).
- You declare `name` and `x` as globals, then never use them. Globals are almost always a bad idea, and unused declarations just clutter your code.
- As @CTX pointed out, you are using recursion (`LogOn` calling `LogOn` calling `MainMenu` calling `LogOn` etc) where iteration would make a lot more sense - you should back out on an error, not call again a level deeper.
- Mixing input/output code and action code is usually a bad decision; it makes your code less flexible and reusable and often harder to debug as well. You should instead have an input/output function which calls an action function with the values it needs.
- Giving separate error messages for bad account number, bad pin number is a security hole; it makes it much easier for would-be attackers to find valid account numbers to attack.
- Looking things up in a list is relatively slow (`O(n)` ie time proportional to the number of items in the list). Use a dict instead (`O(1)` ie constant time - a quick hash calculation takes you right to the item you are looking for).

Here is a fancied-up version; may it give you things to think about:

```
import sys

# version compatibility shim
if sys.hexversion < 0x3000000:
    inp = raw_input   # Python 2.x
else:
    inp = input       # Python 3.x

class Account:
    index = {}

    __slots__ = ("accnum", "pin", "name", "balance")

    @classmethod
    def log_in(cls, accnum, pin):
        key = (accnum, pin)
        acc = Account.index.get(key, None)
        if acc is None:
            raise ValueError("No such login (bad account# or PIN)")
        else:
            return acc

    def __init__(self, accnum, pin, name, balance):
        # save values
        self.accnum = accnum
        self.pin = pin
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance
        # add self to account index
        key = (accnum, pin)
        Account.index[key] = self

# create accounts
Account('00001', '1234', "Luke",  1337)
Account('00002', '4321', "Louis",  420)

def main():
    while True:
        print("\nWelcome to the Bank of Bailey")
        accnum = inp("Please enter your account number: ").strip()
        pin    = inp("Please enter your PIN: ").strip()

        try:
            acc = Account.log_in(accnum, pin)
            print("\nYour account has a current balance of ${:0.2f}".format(acc.balance))
            print("Thank you for banking with us!")
        except ValueError as ve:
            print(ve)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```